# Обновлять время и прибавлять часы и минуты

Tags: java, android, дата, время

Нужно, чтобы программа считывала текущее время пользователя, обновляла его каждую минуту. Также, чтобы выводились время и минуты с формате: 
HH + n часов : mm + t минут

вот как я доставала текущее время:

```
DateFormat dfh = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
final String date = dfh.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Пробовала и другие способы, но приложение либо вылетало, либо показывало какую-то белиберду.
как я пыталась обновить время:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new getTimeEverySecond(), 0, 1000); // ставим на выполнение каждую секунду


static class getTimeEverySecond extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        s = dateFormat.format(date); // каждую секунду обновляем переменную
    }
}
```

при попытке сделать так, как выше, приложение писало много текста.

Также, через while(true), но все горело красным от такого.

как я пыталась прибавлять время:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
 cal.setTime(new Date()); // sets calendar time/date
 cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1); // adds one hour
 cal.getTime();
```

спрашивала вчера похожий вопрос, мне посоветовали доставать время так:

```
DateTime.now().toLocalDate().toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm"))

DateTime.now().plusHours(1).plusMinutes(10).toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE dd MMMM, YYYY"))
```

но, когда я пыталась так сделать, DateTime и DateTimeFormat не распознавались и андроид предлагал сделать новый класс/переменную/метод с такими именами.

Как сделать так, чтобы приложение постоянно обновляло текущее время?
Как сделать так, чтобы можно было вывести время в формате HH + n часов : mm + t минут?

Весь мой код фрагмента, в котором пытаюсь это реализовать это:

```
package com.example.itss;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class PhaseFragment extends Fragment {
    Button timeToWakeUp0;
    Button timeToWakeUp1;
    Button timeToWakeUp2;
    Button timeToWakeUp3;
    Button timeToWakeUp4;
    Button timeToWakeUp5;
    Button timeToWakeUp6;
    Button timeToWakeUp7;

    Button timeToSleep0;
    Button timeToSleep1;
    Button timeToSleep2;
    Button timeToSleep3;
    Button timeToSleep4;
    Button timeToSleep5;
    Button timeToSleep6;
    Button timeToSleep7;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phase_fragment,container, false);


        DateFormat dfh = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        final String date = dfh.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
        cal.setTime(new Date()); // sets calendar time/date
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1); // adds one hour
        cal.getTime();

        DateTime.now().toLocalDate().toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm"));

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new getTimeEverySecond(), 0, 1000);





        timeToWakeUp0 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime0);
        timeToWakeUp0.setText(DateTime.now().plusHours(1).plusMinutes(10).toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm")));
        timeToWakeUp1 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime1);
        timeToWakeUp1.setText(timer + "");
        timeToWakeUp2 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime2);
        timeToWakeUp2.setText(date);
        timeToWakeUp3 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime3);
        timeToWakeUp4 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime4);
        timeToWakeUp5 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime5);
        timeToWakeUp6 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime6);
        timeToWakeUp7 = v.findViewById(R.id.sleeptime7);

        timeToSleep0 = v.findViewById(R.id.wakeuptime0);
        timeToSleep1 = v.findViewById(R.id.wakeuptime1);
        timeToSleep2 = v.findViewById(R.id.wakeuptime2);
        timeToSleep3 = v.findViewById(R.id.wakeuptime3);
        timeToSleep4 = v.findViewById(R.id.wakeuptime4);
        timeToSleep5 = v.findViewById(R.id.wakeuptime5);
        timeToSleep6 = v.findViewById(R.id.wakeuptime6);
        timeToSleep7 = v.findViewById(R.id.wakeuptime7);


        timeToWakeUp0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });

        timeToWakeUp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToWakeUp2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToWakeUp3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToWakeUp4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToWakeUp5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToWakeUp6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToWakeUp7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToSleep0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToSleep1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToSleep2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToSleep3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToSleep4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToSleep5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToSleep6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        timeToSleep7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    static class getTimeEverySecond extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String s = dateFormat.format(date); // каждую секунду обновляем переменную
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Куда выводить-то?

Comment: DateTime и DateTimeFormat  - классы библиотеки Joda Time, перед тем, как их испоьзовать эта библиотека должна быть подключена в проект. Вы пишите программу для ОС Android, каким невероятным образом туда попал стартовый метод "большой" Java - `public static void main(String[] args)` ?

Comment: на кнопку в виде текста

Comment: Я просто гуглила то как это делают другие люди, копировала, вставляла, я знаю что это очень тупо, но у меня дедлайн через 3 недели, поэтому я особо не вникала, просто пыталась сделать так, чтобы программа работала
дада я

Comment: так она точно не будет работать, ни через 3 недели, никогда. Фреймворк Android никаким образом не учитывает наличие метода main() и не стартует его при запуске приложения, а стартует он активити, которая указана в манифесте стартовой, та в свою очередь стартует свои методы жизненного цикла, как onCreate() .. может вам почитать что то по разработке под Android, а потом уже гуглить что то более подходяшее

Comment: нет, нет, это я знаю, эти строчки : Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new getTimeEverySecond(), 0, 1000);
я вставляла в метод onCreate() в одном из фрагментов моего проекта. Непонятно выразилась, извините, просто пример для вопроса копировала - вставляла так

Comment: теперь вам нужно в методе `getTimeEverySecond()` выводить полученное время на виджет, по типу `button.setText(s)`. Оформите код в виде одного целого класса активити, а не отдельные кусочки, которые не понятно где находятся

Comment: хорошо, сейчас.

Comment: то есть, у вас есть 14 кнопок и каждая постоянно должна отображать текущее время + какое то смещение (разное для каждой, если да, то откуда берется это смещение) или какая логика?

Comment: Да, все так как Вы сказали. Смещение я уже поняла как сделать, я его выставляю вручную с помощью joda time. Мне нужно сделать будильники, которые будут ориентироваться на циклы сна человека, то есть каждая кнопка добавляет по 1.5 *n часов с реальному времени. n - количество циклов

Comment: Если вам дают ссылку, её нужно открывать! В build.gradle на уровень приложения добавляете зависимость: implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.10.1.2' (читать здесь: https://habr.com/ru/company/redmadrobot/blog/275515/), дальше инициализируете JodaTime: JodaTimeAndroid.init(this); Можно в том же активити где вы и используете данную библиотеку в onCreate(), но лучше на уровень Application (читать здесь: https://ru-code-android.livejournal.com/4594.html, там ниже будет про класс Aplication и зачем он нужен)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение задачи с использованием класса `Timer` не очень правильное хотя бы потому, что он не будет срабатывать точно с началом каждой минуты, а у вас, как я понял какой то будильник.

Предлагаю использовать системное широковещательное оповещение, которое рассылается в начале каждой минуты. В своем приложении мы подписываемся на него и при наступлении события обновляем время в виджетах.

Так же код обновления кнопок вызывается каждую минуту и хорошим тоном будет сократить количество создаваемых при этом объектов. В частности для получения времени и вычисления смещения используются статические системные классы (как `System.currentTimeMillis()` и `TimeUnit`), которые не создают объектов, вместо использования классов `Date`, `Calendar` или `JodaTime` - расчеты не такие сложные, чтобы использовать здесь их.

Весь код выглядит так (для простоты в примере только три кнопки):

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

    Button timer1, timer2, timer3;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    int timeShifts [][] = {
            {0, 0}, //  смещение времени - 0 часов
            {1, 30}, // смещение времени 1 час 30 мин
            {3, 0} // смещение времени 3 часа
    };
    final int HOUR = 0;
    final int MINUTE = 1;
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        timer1 = v.findViewById(R.id.timer1);
        timer2 = v.findViewById(R.id.timer2);
        timer3 = v.findViewById(R.id.timer3);

        // устанавливаем время на кнопках
        setTime();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

                // обновляем время каждую минуту
                    setTime();
            }
        };

        // подписываемся на системное событие изменения времени (срабатывает раз в минуту)
        getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // отписываемся от события
        if (broadcastReceiver != null)getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }


    // метод устанавливает время на кнопках
    private void setTime() {
        long curentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timer1.setText(timeFormat.format(curentTime+ timeToMillis(timeShifts[0][HOUR],timeShifts[0][MINUTE]))); // текущее время
        timer2.setText(timeFormat.format(curentTime + timeToMillis(timeShifts[1][HOUR],timeShifts[1][MINUTE]))); // текущее время + 1 ч 30 мин
        timer3.setText(timeFormat.format(curentTime + timeToMillis(timeShifts[2][HOUR],timeShifts[2][MINUTE]))); // текущее время + 3 ч.
    }

    // метод переводит часы и минуты в милисекунды
    private long timeToMillis(int hour, int minute){

        return TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hour) + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minute);
    }
}
```

вы можете менять смещение времени в процессе работы программы следующим образом (изменяем смещение времени на второй кнопке на 2 часа 15 минут):

```
timeShifts[1][HOUR] = 2;
timeShifts[1][MINUTE] = 15;
setTime();
```

ps: отсчет кнопок начинается с 0

Данный код только выводит текст на кнопки и обновляет его каждую минуту, никаких функций реального будильника он не выполняет. Так же никакого действия не будет происходить, если программа не запущена или находится в фоне (то есть условный будильник при этом не сработает). Если вам нужно, чтобы и при закрытом приложении или в фоне тоже шел отсчет времени, то для этого есть класс [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) ([пример испльзования](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/alarmmanager.php)). Вы можете использовать код выше для интерфейса приложения, а реальный будильник устанавливать уже через `AlarmManager`

Comment: broadcastReceiver горит красным, хотя я импортировала класс, что может быть не так?

Comment: так сразу нельзя сказать, почему у вас это происходит. при наведении курсора на выделенное красным что пишет, в чем проблема? вообще я тестировал код, который в ответе - он работает. попробуйте полностью скопировать его, включая импорты (можно создать тестовый проект), а потом доработать под свои задачи, если не получится решить иначе.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, я попробую

Comment: я попробовала, долго тыкалась, но в итоге все заработало, однако время все равно не обновляется так как надо. Если повисеть во фрагменте минуты 2-3, то время обновляться не будет, если переключиться на другую вкладку, а потом снова в нужный фрагмент, тогда обновится. в любом случае, спасибо, я надеюсь я не достала Вас тупыми вопросами :`D

Comment: вы что то делаете не так, повторю, что код я проверял и все работает - время изменяется каждую минуту. если вам нужно непременно фрагмент, завтра потестирую на фрагменте, может там какие то нюансы ..

Comment: @ЕкатеринаДеркач изменил под фрагмент и протестировал - код работает и время изменяется каждую минуту